# Issue using JSON library of Vert.x when I use json.encode

Tags: java, json, vert.x

I am trying to use `json.encode` of `vert.x` and am having a weird issue.
I am new with `vert.x` so I really need help here.
This line of code is the one that causes me a problem: `resp.setData(Json.encode(trustBalancingOutputDataListResult));`

I am trying to call `json.encode` by passing my `arrayList` of object type `TrustBalancingOutputData`.

My object type `TrustBalancingOutputData` has 3 attributes type `HashMap` and it throws me the following exception:

```
Jun 05, 2019 8:46:33 AM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.fma.wb.integration.reportsmodule.dto.trust.TrustBalancingOutputData
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$45(Collectors.java:907)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.fma.wb.integration.reportsmodule.utils.io.TrustExcelFileGenerator.getBase64GeneratedFile(TrustExcelFileGenerator.java:47)
at com.fma.wb.integration.reportsmodule.verticles.MainReportVerticle.lambda$null$17(MainReportVerticle.java:455)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:121)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:83)
at com.fma.wb.integration.reportsmodule.services.TrustBalancingService.lambda$calculateRpTotals$24(TrustBalancingService.java:1190)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:76)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:289)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339)
at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried to remove the 3 attributes type `HashMap` I have in my object `TrustBalancingOutputData` and I do not have an issue at all. That confirms me that the issue I have here is based on the 3 attributes type `HashMap` I have in my `TrustBalancingOutputData` object

Here is my code:

```
InternalResponse resp=new InternalResponse();
resp.setCause(1);
resp.setData(Json.encode(trustBalancingOutputDataListResult));
```

`trustBalancingOutputDataListResult` is an `ArrayList<TrustBalancingOutputData>`
and `TrustBalancingOutputData` has the following attributes:

```
private HashMap<String,String> listTrust =  new HashMap<>();
    private String achTotal;
    private String iclTotal;
    private String rpSolutionsTotal;
    //private String formula = "";
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> excelFileBottomData = new HashMap<>();
```

I expect that my `trustBalancingOutputDataListResult arrayList` can be converted to a string when I call `Json.encode(trustBalancingOutputDataListResult)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of Jackson, library that Vert.x uses under the hood for JSON serialization.

You have two options to solve it:

1. Don't use Vert.x JSON for encoding, but something like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
2. Use wrapper classes.

Instead of

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> excelFileBottomData = new HashMap<>();
```

Declare something like

```
private ExcelFileBottomData data = new ExcelFileBottomData();
```

And:

```
class ExcelFileBottomData {
   @JsonProperty("excelFileBottomData")
   HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data;
}
```